# Meaning of the term "concentrated in degree zero"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am studying about Koszul complex from an article, to describe this the Author used

> Consider the ring $R$ as a differential Graded Algebra concentrated in degree zero, . . .

I searched google for the term "concentrated in degree zero", but didn't find anything satisfactory.

Can anyone please explain the term to me?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: It usually means the nonzero degree parts are zero. That is, if $R=\bigoplus_{i\geq 0} R_i$ is a ($\mathbb{N}$-) graded algebra, then $R=R_0$, and $R_n=0$ for $n\neq 0$.

Comment: so, usually this is the trivial gradation of an algebra?

Comment: I'm bumping this post.  Does anyone have any idea what this means in Wiebel?!